# Dynamodb schema design for optimal queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to nosql and after reading up on dynamodb i have some confusion on how to model my use case.  I've got an app that has users and clubs.  The users can belong to 0-many clubs.  users can also be an owner of a club which grants them enhanced privileges.

i was thinking of having 2 tables to manage the club/user relationship.  1 with a partition key of user_name and a sort key of club_name the other with a partition key of club_name and a sorty_key of user_name.  These should allow me to efficiently query for all users in my club and all clubs i'm a member of.

How would i efficiently query for all clubs i'm not a member of and all users who are not in my club?

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe you should use a relational database or hive.**

With DynamoDB. You can use 3 tables.

- Table 1:User table,use user_id as hash_key and have field user_name.
- Table 2:Club table,use club_id as hash_key and have field club_name.
- Table 3:Relationship table,use user_id and club_id as hash_key and
  range_key.

But you can't get result use one query.

**I don't recommended do this query use dynamodb.**